# 21 bytes Ethereum address with "0x" in 20 bytes address data type

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, addresses, data-types

I am learning solidity. Public address is dervied from last 20 bytes of public key. I have read that address data type has 20 bytes size and in many programme I have seen that they are equated to an address like

`address val = 0x9361005EA8041821edF4BeaF5B0518d9e75AeB13 ;`

We have stored our address with `0x` at the front which makes it of 42 hexadecimal digits i.e. 21 bytes , so how address data type can store beyond its limit ?

Comment: `0x` is just a symbol used as prefix to denote hexadecimal numbers. It doesn't add bits to the number.

Answer (score 3):

An `address` data type stores 20 bytes value that represents an Ethereum address. An Ethereum address is always represented in hexadecimal format and prefixed with `0x`. Prefixing by `0x` does increase the total byte to 21 bytes, but doesn't mean the original `address` data type can store beyond 20 bytes. It's like if a cup can hold a maximum capacity of 8 oz of water, but doesn't mean adding a cap to the cup will increase its maximum capacity to 10 oz (although the total weight might increase slightly). The cap is there so the water doesn't spill over (like how adding `0x` to the prefix lets the receiver of the address know it's in hexadecimal format).

Comment: Excellent analogy!